# Swift Text Box Issue

Tags: swift

This application is designed to let their users rate the dorms at York College. To learn the language I used the apple developer website and followed their step by step instructions to make the basic application. After adding some small features I tried to add a text box for users to add a description of each dorm. It runs but it doesn't seem to display the text that has been added to the description section. This is written in an older version of Swift.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1

```
     **MealTableViewController.swift**
    //  MealTableViewController.swift
    //  FoodTracker
    //
    //  Created by Jane Appleseed on 11/15/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import os.log

    class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        //MARK: Properties

        var meals = [Meal]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

            // Load any saved meals, otherwise load sample data.
            if let savedMeals = loadMeals() {
                meals += savedMeals
            }
            else {
                // Load the sample data.
                loadSampleMeals()
            }
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        //MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return meals.count
        }


        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
            let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"

            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
                fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
            }

            // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
            let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

            cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
            cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
            cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating
            cell.descriptionLabel?.text = meal.desc

            print(meal.desc!)

            return cell
        }



        // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
            return true
        }



        // Override to support editing the table view.
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                // Delete the row from the data source
                meals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                saveMeals()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            } else if editingStyle == .insert {
                // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
            }    
        }


        /*
        // Override to support rearranging the table view.
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
            return true
        }
        */


        //MARK: - Navigation

        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

            switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

            case "AddItem":
                os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

            case "ShowDetail":
                guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
                }

                guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
                }

                guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                    fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
                }

                let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
                mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

            default:
                fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
            }
        }


        //MARK: Actions

        @IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
            if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {

                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    // Update an existing meal.
                    meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
                }
                else {
                    // Add a new meal.
                    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)

                    meals.append(meal)
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                }

                // Save the meals.
                saveMeals()
                os_log("Saved Meals?", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

            }
        }

        //MARK: Private Methods
        //*** MAKE SAMPLE DORMS ***
        private func loadSampleMeals() {

            let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")
            let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")
            let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")

            guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Northside Commons", photo: photo1, rating: 5, desc: "Great Rooms, air conditioning") else {
                fatalError("Unable to instantiate dorm1")
            }

            guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Beard Hall", photo: photo2, rating: 2, desc: "Lots of space") else {
                fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
            }

            guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Mannor Hall", photo: photo3, rating: 3, desc: "No air conditioning, fun floor mates") else {
                fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
            }

            meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
        }

        private func saveMeals() {
            let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
            if isSuccessfulSave {
                os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            } else {
                os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
            }
        }

        private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]?  {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Meal]
        }

    }



//
//  Meal.swift
//  FoodTracker
//
//  Created by Jane Appleseed on 11/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import os.log


class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var rating: Int
    var desc: String?

    //MARK: Archiving Paths
    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

    //MARK: Types

    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let photo = "photo"
        static let rating = "rating"
        static let desc = "desc"
    }

    //MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int, desc: String?) {

        // The name must not be empty
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        /*
        guard !desc?.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
*/
        // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
        guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else {
            return nil
        }

        // The rates must be above 0
        guard (rating >= 0) else {
            return nil
        }

        // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
        if name.isEmpty || rating < 0  {
            return nil
        }

        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.rating = rating
        self.desc = desc

    }

    //MARK: NSCoding

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
        aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
        aCoder.encode(desc, forKey: PropertyKey.desc)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
            os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
        }
        /*
        guard (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.desc) as? String) != nil else {
                   os_log("Unable to decode the description for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
                   return nil
               }
        */
        // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
        let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage

        let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating, desc: "desc")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a hard and fast answer (it's hard to give one without a XIB/Storyboard file to take a peek at), but I see that your description label (`cell.descriptionLabel?`) is an optional. I would check to see if your description label actually exists, like this:

```
if let descriptionLabel = cell.descriptionLabel? {
    descriptionLabel.text = meal.desc
} else {
    print("This label doesn't exist!")    
}
```

Then check your output!